# Magento : Extend Caching Time For External JS

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, caching

I want to Increase Expire time for External JS how can I achieve this?

Extend from `.htaccess` doesn't work for this.

[image]

And We can use CDN for External JS , like zopim , zendesk , google fonts , google JS etc.

Answer (score 0):

What Are you asking is just unrealistic because external js Is external js.

So how can you cache external resource in your server.

all this things should be done by the where those resource actually stores.

> And We can use CDN for External JS , like zopim , zendesk , google fonts , google JS etc.

For above question :

see in cdn you put your own resource and libraries in cdn means. once you download jQuery library and put that library in cdn and fetch that library from CDN.

But here you don't have those libraries . first download those libraries and then upload to your CDN server,  and fetch those libraries from CDN this way only you can use CDN

Comment: Actually I dont know how to extend cache time thats why i'm asking.Any Solution for that?

Comment: NO by the there is no solution except you download to your local server